# Get Outlook Attachment information in Web Add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2019, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Web Add-in running on Azure. I am using a Controller to get the Outlook attachment details from the Outlook Exchange server (this is working fine). After I get the Attachment details, I call a .cs class to extract the attachment infor (name, size, etc). I am able to get the attachment Name, but not the attachment Size and Content. See code below.

This is crazy, I can get the System.IO.FileInfo and reference the Name but not the Length - I get this error when I reference the Length ***Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\AWS_Knowledge.docx'***

I am at a total loss - why am I able to get the Name and not the other info like (length). Any help will be welcome - thanks

```
public static OutLookAttachment(FileAttachment fileAttachment)
{
//I have tried all these differenct approaches to get the file info - 
//the below code return a local D:\.... path
string attachmentName1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileAttachment.Name);
string attachmentName2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), 
fileAttachment.FileName);

//I settled with this code since this is running on Azure/Website
//Returns Website D:\home\site\wwwroot\AWS_Knowledge.docx* path/
string attachmentName = 
System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString(), 
fileAttachment.Name);`

/*get the file info*/
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(attachmentName);

/*get file data*/
//this works
string n = fi.Name;

//this works
string fn = fi.FullName;

//I get the error here saying Could not find file 
'D:\home\site\wwwroot\AWS_Knowledge.docx'
long length = fi.Length;

/*if I reference the passed in attachment directly, I get the below results*/

//this works - I get the file name
string fileName = fileAttachment.Name;

//this returns 0 - basically no data
long fielSize = fileAttachment.Size;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if file actually exists or not? You can directly check that path or you can use `bool exists = fi.Exists;`

Comment: Thx for the response; the file exits, I can get other info about the file (like file name, file type), but not the length or content. Also, I get the full file path with the file listed. I will try your suggestion and update...

Comment: Ok, I am totally confused here - I can get the file info such as Name (below),  but when I get if the file exists, I the **File Does Not Exists**                                                                 
This is an Outlook attachment I passed in to the method.//this worsk, I get the file name
string fn = fi.Name;
//The if returns File Does Not Exists
if (fi.Exists)
{
 errorMsg += "File Exists \n";
}
else
{
 errorMsg += "File Does Not Exists \n";
}

Comment: Can you answer following questions: 1. How the add-in attachment info is getting to server? 2. Which JS API you are using to get the attachment?

Comment: The Outlook Web Add-in uses HTML/JS - The JS gets the Outlook email attachment and passed it to a Controller Class deployed on Azure - the Controller gets the details about the attachment from the Outlook Exchange Server; the Controllers calls a  .cs class also deployed on the same Azure server and passed in the attachment. So, basically, the attachment is passed in from the Controller to the .cs class.

Comment: I resolve the issue - basically, get the website path and load the attachment - don't forget to delete the attachment to avoid your site being loaded with attachments.

//Here is the code

//Get app path
string appPatch = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());
                    
//Load the attachment to Azure Server
fileAttachment.Load(appPatch + fileAttachment.Name);

//Done with the attachment - delete from the site
System.IO.File.Delete(fileAttachment.FileName);

Comment: Is the issue resolved for you?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue - basically, get the website path and load the attachment - don't forget to delete the attachment to avoid your site being loaded with attachments.

//Here is the code

//Get app path
string appPatch = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());

//Load the attachment to Azure Server
fileAttachment.Load(appPatch + fileAttachment.Name);

//Done with the attachment - delete from the site
System.IO.File.Delete(fileAttachment.FileName);